# Installing Rails app on Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, heroku

How would I add a rails project to my Linux Server? Is it the same as PHP, or simple HTML?

I've seen many pushing the apps to Heroku, but how would I push it to my own server?

Comment: use capistrano deployment. see https://github.com/capistrano/rails

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tutorials in the internet. Some keywords that will help you in your research:

- nginx + unicorn + rails
- nginx/apache + Phussion passenger + rails

nginx and Apache are web servers; unicorn and passenger are application servers for Ruby (Rack).

The basic idea is to configure `server` (nginx) or `virtualhost` (apache) directives to point to your Rails app public folder and redirect to your app server.